# how to remove only ext3 here in unix? filename.ext1.ext2.ext3

Tags: bash, shell, unix

example file: filename.ext1.ext2.ext3 how to remove only ext3 here in unix bash shell under sun solaris? in all directories:

```
find . -name "*.ext3" |  mv '{}' ?
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe the output of the `find` command into a `while read` loop. Even file names with spaces will be read correctly in this manner. Do not use a `for file in $(find ...)` construct. It's very inefficient (the find must complete before the for loop starts, it will have problems with files with spaces in the name, and it can overload the command line buffer which will happen without the slightest indication.

You can also use the `$[var%name}` construct The `%` means small right filter. It filters the right side of an environment variable with the matching glob. A single `%` means match the smallest possible amount. A double `%%` means match the largest amount. The `#` and `##` are for the left side of the string.

Also be careful to use quotation marks around your file names incase of spaces in the name.

```
find . -type f -name "*.ext3" | while read file
do
   mv "$file" "${file%.ext3}" 
done
```

A bit safer might be to use `find . -name "*.exe" -print0` which will separate file names with nulls instead of returns. This is useful incase a  is in the file name. Then, you have to set your `IFS` variable to handle nulls and not spaces, tabs, and NL.

Comment: `-print0` is not portable and painful to use. The best would be: `find -type f -name '*.ext3' -exec rename '.ext3' '' {} +`.

Comment: @michal gorny: I am not familiar with the `rename` command in Unix. The `-print0` extension is standard in GNU, BSD, and SysV versions of the `find` command. What isn't standard is the `xargs` to interpret it. However, as long as file names don't contain <NL>, the code should work. I considered using `-exec`, but the problem is that the user wanted to rename a file `foo.bar.txt.ext3` to `foo.bar.txt`. The `${word%glob}` syntax in BASH would be perfect, but won't work with `-exec` because `-exec` doesn't invoke a shell. Thus, piping through to a while read was the best way of doing this.

Comment: One way of hacking `-exec` is: `find -type f -name '*.ext3' -exec sh -c 'for fn; do mv "${fn}" "${fn%.ext3}"; done' IGNORED {} +` but that's already getting scary and not sure about portability of `sh -c command argv' (although it works with bash, dash & posh).

Answer (score 2):

It would be:

```
for i in `find . -type f -name "*.ext3"` ; do mv $i $(echo $i | sed -e '/\.ext3$//') ; done
```

In the case the files have spaces, you can do this slightly different:

```
find . -type f -name "*.ext3" | while read file ; do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed -e '/\.ext3$//')" ; done
```

Comment: I want to get rid of the extension3 in this case: not delete the file.

Comment: `mv` renames the file, it doesn't delete it.

Comment: OK, sorry, I misunderstood the queston. I edited the response.

Comment: what about file names with spaces?

Comment: @ghostdog: what about? They are evil, and every user should be instructed not to use them. They make every UNIX script more difficult to write, maintain, understand, etc. Moreover, they are NOT needed. Come on, almost no programming language allows spaes in variables and nobody has fainted... :)